# Powershell filter ignored in pipeline

Tags: powershell, pipeline, msmq

I am writing a Chef library to make writing a custom resource for managing Microsoft MSMQ resources on Windows Server easier.  Chef interfaces with Windows using Powershell 5.1.

I want to raise an error if my call to `Get-MsmqQueue` fails and returns `$Null`.  To do so, I have created a filter to raise an error if the value is invalid.  This seems to work if I pipeline a `$Null` value, but if the value is returned from `Get-MsmqQueue` and is `$Null`, it does not work.

Does anybody have an idea why line #5 does not raise an error, even if the value is equal to `$Null`?

```
#1 filter Test-Null{ if ($Null -ne $_) { $_ } else { Write-Error "object does not exist" }}

#2 $a = $Null
#3 $a | Test-Null | ConvertTo-Json     # this raises an error

#4 $a = Get-MsmqQueue -Name DoesNotExist
#5 $a | Test-Null | ConvertTo-Json     # this does NOT raise an error
#6 $Null -eq $a                        # this evaluates to $True
```

Comment: Functions in pipelines can be tricky.  [mcpmag](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/05/20/functions-that-support-the-pipeline.aspx)

Comment: That filter can be false with a 0 or empty string.  Here's another example:  `$a = cmd /c 'echo hi | find "there"'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A cmdlet that produces *no* output doesn't actually emit `$null` - it (implicitly) emits the `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` singleton** that *in expressions* acts *like* `$null`, but in *enumeration contexts* such as the pipeline enumerates *nothing* and therefore sends nothing through the pipeline - unlike an *actual* `$null` value.

```
# True $null *is* sent through the pipeline.
PS> $var = $null; $var | ForEach-Object { 'here' }
here 

# [System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value is *not*.
# `& {}` is a simple way to create this value.
PS> $var = & {}; $var | ForEach-Object { 'here' }
# !! No output
```

As of PowerShell 7.0, **`[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` can only be discovered *indirectly*, using *obscure techniques*** such as the following:

```
# Only returns $true if $var contains
# [System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value
$null -eq $var -and @($var).Count -eq 0
```

This lack of discoverability is problematic, and improving the situation by enabling the following is the subject of [this GitHub proposal](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13465).

```
$var -is [AutomationNull] # WISHFUL THINKING as of PowerShell 7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

A different way to test it.  This tests the standard output being non-null, not the exit code.  I'm not testing the equality.  The assignment is a side effect.

```
if (not ($a = Get-MsmqQueue -Name DoesNotExist)) { 
  Write-Error "object does not exist" }
```